# jQuery - Getting returned data from ajaxStop

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Just wondering if anyone knows how I can get the returned json data from ajaxStop...

I know there is a data property within event object, but it is undefined, even though data is being returned correctly...

Cheers
Anthony

---

UPDATE:

When using Success or complete I can see that the responseText within request is populated, but it is a string type and not a json type...

Any idea how I can get access to the typed returned data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ajaxStop` is meant to be used for handling interrupted AJAX requests. Although it is also triggered after ajaxComplete, it is never passed any data.

You probably want to use one of [`ajaxComplete`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/ajaxComplete#callback), [`ajaxSuccess`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/ajaxSuccess#callback) or [`ajaxError`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/ajaxError#callback).

Answer (score 0):

ajaxStop doesn't get any of the data returned on the ajax call passed in as parameter